# Synaptics settings get applied correctly from /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d but then reset?

Tags: linux, macintosh, touchpad, synaptic

I have a BCM5974 touchpad device which gets loaded incorrectly by Xorg despite being seemingly correctly configured. I have a simple /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-synaptics.conf file:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "TouchPad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "FingerHigh" "50"
    Option "RTCornerButton" "0"
    Option "RBCornerButton" "0"
    Option "MinSpeed" "0.7"
    Option "MaxSpeed" "1.7"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
    Option "TapAndDragGesture" "off"
    Option "PalmDetect" "off"
EndSection
```

I want to see these settings when I run synclient after X has started to see they are actually applied. However, they are not.

I look in my Xorg.0.log and find that the settings get applied, only to be reset.

```
[   211.875] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   211.875] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   211.875] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
[   211.875] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "no"
[   211.875] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   211.876] (II) config/udev: Adding input device bcm5974 (/dev/input/event7)
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "TouchPad"
[   211.876] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   211.876] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[   211.876] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   211.876]    compiled for 1.15.2, module version = 1.7.4
[   211.876]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   211.876]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[   211.876] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'bcm5974'
[   211.876] (**) bcm5974: always reports core events
[   211.876] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   211.906] (II) synaptics: bcm5974: found clickpad property
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: x-axis range -4750 - 5280 (res 0)
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: y-axis range -150 - 6730 (res 0)
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: pressure range 0 - 256
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: finger width range 0 - 16
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: buttons: left double triple
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: Vendor 0x5ac Product 0x263
[   211.907] (**) Option "FingerHigh" "50"
[   211.907] (**) Option "RTCornerButton" "0"
[   211.907] (**) Option "RBCornerButton" "0"
[   211.907] (**) Option "PalmDetect" "off"
[   211.907] (**) Option "MinSpeed" "0.7"
[   211.907] (**) Option "MaxSpeed" "1.7"
[   211.907] (**) Option "TapAndDragGesture" "off"
[   211.907] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
[   211.907] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: touchpad found
[   211.907] (**) bcm5974: always reports core events
[   211.921] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.2/input/input10/event7"
[   211.921] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "bcm5974" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 10)
[   211.921] (**) synaptics: bcm5974: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 1.4
[   211.921] (**) synaptics: bcm5974: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 2.43
[   211.921] (**) synaptics: bcm5974: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.016
[   211.921] (**) bcm5974: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[   211.921] (**) bcm5974: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[   211.921] (**) bcm5974: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   211.921] (**) bcm5974: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   211.922] (--) synaptics: bcm5974: touchpad found
[   211.922] (II) config/udev: Adding input device bcm5974 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   211.922] (**) bcm5974: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

I see from e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/26290/50-synaptics-conf-options-not-working that having the synaptics driver double loaded might result in this. The fix is supposedly to have MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" included, but I already have this in my 60-synaptics.conf file. However, I'm not sure that my problem is even the same (that it gets double loaded).

What is the correct way to configure that device such that the settings get applied correctly? I know I could probably load this from .xinitrc or maybe some other executable file. But shouldn't this work from the xorg.conf.d directly too? Clearly there is some misconfiguration or other user fault here that I'm overlooking.